# How to Extract Queue Name, Priority, and Message ID from RabbitMQ Inbound Endpoint Messages in WSO2 MI 4.2?

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2, message-queue, wso2-micro-integrator, metadata-extractor

I'm currently working on a project using WSO2 Micro Integrator (MI) 4.2, where I've set up an inbound endpoint to consume messages from RabbitMQ. In this scenario, I need to extract specific metadata such as the queue name, priority, and message ID from each incoming message and use this information to update the message status in a database.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

Extract the queue name from which the message is consumed.
Retrieve the priority of the message.
Obtain the message ID.
Update the message status as consumed in a database.
Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this within the context of WSO2 MI 4.2? I'm specifically looking for assistance in configuring the inbound endpoint to facilitate the extraction of this metadata and then processing it within the integration sequence.

Any code snippets, configuration examples, or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The queue name is extracted from the RabbitMQ connection properties, not from the message context.
The queue name is set when the connection is established and the consumer is initialized. It's not a property that's associated with each message. Therefore, it's not possible to extract the queue name from an individual message using a property expression and also it is simillar for the priority as well.
As an example If you need to use the queue name within your sequence, you could set it as a property of the sequence when the inject sequence is initialized. Here's an example of how you could do this:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="processMessage">
    <property name="QueueName" value="your_queue_name"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="QueueName" expression="get-property('QueueName')"/>
        <property name="MessageID" expression="get-property('rabbitmq.message.id')"/>
    </log>
    <!-- Add your database update logic here -->
</sequence>
```

In the above example, replace "your_queue_name" with the name of your queue. This will set the queue name as a property of the sequence, and you can then use the get-property('QueueName') expression to retrieve it.

To update the message status in a database, you can use the DBReport mediator. You would need to configure a datasource in the Micro Integrator and then use the DBReport mediator to update the database.